# How to call registration page in lightbox?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins

I am working on WordPress .I have 1 plugin "Register Plus Redux" will generates registration form on http://xyz.info/wp-login.php?action=register  and i am using simple lightbox which will display the content of that page in lightbox ,Please suggest any solution for the same

That plugin also doesnt provide any shortcode

Please Help 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a light box installed, then grab the class code for it and wrap your registration link with the class?

```
<a href="http://xyz.info/wp-login.php?action=register" class="lightbox">Link to Lightbox</a>
```

Comment: So what do you want to do? Put the registration page in the lightbox?

Comment: michaelbirchall.com@ - yes right i want the same registration page coming on registration page in lightbox